# ReactJS - How to get focus on component after make visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus

I had a `<div>` with a `<p>` child component I name `SocialPostwithCSS`, and `onClick` would cause it to hide, change the state to `editing: true` and a `<textarea>` would show up and I would use `this.textarea.focus` with the textarea having `ref={(input)=>{this.textarea=input}}` and had no problem.

I needed to autosize the area, so I downloaded the NPM package `TextareaAutosize`, now I'm having issues focusing on this text area. I check, the npm TextareAutosize file has `class` and is not stateless. **Currently `this.textarea` is returning `undefined`**

**Summary: How can I focus on `<TextareaAutosize />` after `<div>` `onClick` 
 which causes the state change to show `<TextareaAutosize>`?**

File Below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import SocialPostWithCSS from './SocialPostWithCSS'
import TextareaAutosize from 'react-autosize-textarea'

class SocialPost extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            message: this.props.socialPost.message,
            editing: false
        }
    }
    _clickToEdit() {
        this.textarea.focus()
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {(!this.state.editing) ?
                    <div onClick={async ()=>{await this.setState({editing: true});this._clickToEdit}}>
                        <SocialPostWithCSS >{this.state.message}</SocialPostWithCSS>
                    </div>
                    :<div>
                        <TextareaAutosize
                            onBlur={() => {this.setState({ editing: false})}}
                            type='text'
                            ref={(input)=>{this.textarea=input}}
                            value={this.state.message}
                            />
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default SocialPost
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [looking at the code](https://github.com/buildo/react-autosize-textarea/blob/master/src/TextareaAutosize.js), it appears that TextareaAutosize exposes the inner ref through a prop named innerRef. So change your code like this:

```
<TextareaAutosize
    onBlur={() => {this.setState({ editing: false})}}
    type='text'
    innerRef={(input)=>{this.textarea=input}}
    value={this.state.message}
/>
```

Comment: You Sir, area  genius. This worked! Do you mind telling me what you mean by innerRef? Do you mean this code snipet, line 72-79 `  saveDOMNodeRef = ref => {
    const { innerRef } = this.props;

    if (innerRef) {
      innerRef(ref);
    }

    this.textarea = ref;`

Comment: `ref` gives you access to the underlying dom node of a component. But TextareaAutosize doesn't have a dom node, not directly anyway. Instead, it's wrapping around a <textarea> element, and it's *that* element that has a dom node. In cases like these, it's common for a component to get the ref from its child, and then expose it to the outside world, usually through a prop named innerRef. And TextareaAutosize is following this convention.

Comment: You'll notice on line 102 of TextAreaAutosize, that's where it's getting the ref of the <textarea>. And then the lines you mentioned are exposing that ref out to you via the innerRef prop

Answer (score 1):

this.textarea is returning undefined onclick to the div because initially when this.state.editing is false TextareaAutosize component was not rendered and hence this.textarea was not initialized by the mounted instance of the component.